# what is the location of node-modules

Tags: nodejs, javascript

I want to see my all packages and modules of node-module. Please tell me its the location in ubuntu 18.04. such as `/path/to/node-module`. Moreover, How to see the code of modules such as **http** module or **fs** module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Global libraries**

You can run `npm list -g` to see which global libraries are installed and where they're located. Use `npm list -g | head -1` for truncated output showing just the path.

On Unix systems they are normally placed in `/usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` when installed globally. If you set the NODE_PATH environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

**Non-global libraries**

Non-global libraries are installed the node_modules sub folder in the folder you are currently in. You can run `npm list` to see the installed non-global libraries for your current location.

Comment: Thank You for your help......

Answer (score 3):

You can see the local location like this:

```
$ npm root
/home/<user>/<path>/node_modules
```

and the global location like this:

```
$ npm root -g
/usr/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 1):

node_modules installed globally are rooted in the library where sudo admin is necessary to access

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```